# read command help in bash

Tags: bash

I wanted to read output of a command in an array:

Something like:

(reformatted for code using {} above the input box)

```
var=`echo tell told till`
echo "$var" | while read temp; do echo $temp ; done
```

This program will output:

```
tell 
told 
till
```

I had two questions:

1. Read command reads from stdin. But in the above case how is it reading? echo puts the values on stdout.
2. I wanted to know how to put those elements in an array? Basically how to put elements in stdout in an array. Read -a command can put the elements in stdin, but i wanted stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put elements from stdout into array, eg

```
declare -a array
array=( $(my command that generates stdout) ) #eg array=( $(ls))
```

If you have a variable and want to put into array

```
$> var="tell till told"
$> read -a array <<< $var
$> echo ${array[1]}
till
$> echo ${array[0]}
tell
```

OR just

```
array=($var)
```

From bash reference:

```
   Here Strings
       A variant of here documents, the format is:

              <<<word

       The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.
```

Comment: Tanks a ton for the soltion. It works!. Could you please tell me what is  <<< symbol? I know about redirection, but its not the same. Kindly explain.

Answer (score 1):

A pipe ("`|`") connects the preceding command's stdout to the following command's stdin.

Comment: Then why does'nt echo "$var" | read -a temp , store the values tell,told,till in temp array?

Answer (score 1):

To split a string into words you can simply use:

```
for word in $string;
do 
    echo $word;
done;
```

So to do what you're asking

```
while read line
do
    for word in $line
    do
        echo $word
    done
done
```

And as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said, a pipe connects the left side's stdout to the right side's stdin.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a pipe:

```
command1 | command2
```

The output of command1, written to the stdout, will be the input for command2 (stdin). The pipe "transforms" stdout to stdin.

And for the array:
You give values to the array whith:

```
array=(val1 val2 val3)
```

So just try it:

```
array=($var)
```

You've got now $var in $array:

```
> echo ${array[*]}
tell
told
till

> echo ${array[1]}
told
```

Is this what you mean?